# Chimp.js configuration

Tags: javascript, testing, end-to-end, cucumberjs, chimp.js

I am using Chimp.js(with Cucumber.js) and all the tests need to pass a login page.

I know webdriverIO uses testrunner config file for something like `.before()` and `.after()`.

How would be the best way to achieve that with Chimp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cucumber.js before and after hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js#hooks) with Chimp:

```
// tests/features/clearDatabase.js
var clearDatabase = function() {

  this.Before(function() {
    server.call('/fixtures/clearDatabase');
  });

};

module.exports = clearDatabase;
```

Comment: It might be better to put this code into a sub-folder like "tests/features/_support/hooks/before_hooks.js" as it is not a feature.